# Allow absolute element to have automatic width bigger than parent

Tags: css

I have a list of countries that is displayed as an absolute element inside a relative element.

The HTML is:

```
<div class="screener-filter">
    <div class="screener-filter-dropdown">
        <div class="dropdown-item">Afghanistan</div>
        <div class="dropdown-item">Albania</div>
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS is:

```
.screener-filter {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.screener-filter-dropdown {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 110%;
}
```

The problem is, the `.screener-filter-dropdown` automatically fits the width of the parent, and some countries' names can't fit in one line for that reason. Take American Samoa for example:

[image]

My question is, how do I allow `.screener-filter-dropdown` to have an automatic width based on the width of the country names, not limited by the width of the parent?

Comment: white-space:nowrap to the items?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add to `screener-filter-dropdown` class `width:fit-content` or `width:max-content` ?

Comment: This doesn't help, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
.screener-filter {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%; // <=
}
```

Comment: I can't have the `screener-filter` with 100% width, there are multiple in one line (hence the `display: inline-block`).

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it